# Pregunta General respecto al login Laravel/Android

Tags: android, laravel

tengo un pregunta.

Estoy haciendo un apartado de `login` en laravel y a la vez esta base de datos esta conectada con una aplicación de `android`, el problema es cuando creo un usuario en Laravel obviamente me encripta la contraseña, y puedo acceder, pero al pasarme en la aplicación de android no me deja `logearme`, y viceversa, en android igualmente no encripta la contraseña pero sucede lo mismo.

La pregunta seria ¿Que puedo hacer para que el `login` sea exitoso en ambas plataformas?

Nota: con la password desenciptada en laravel aun asi no me deja logearme en laravel

Edit:

Añadiendo, configure de esta manera el `modelo` con tal de que pueda acceder a los datos con `auth` de laravel

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```

al intentar `logear` con las credenciales creadas desde un `registo` en android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me manda de regreso con estos errores

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

igualmente en android me dice que no `existe el usuario o registro`

Comment: Hola Dohko, tendrias que subir codigo del login que no funciona, detalles del log, etc, cualquier informacion que ayude a la gente a darte una mano, asi como esta la pregunta es muy amplia, nadie podria darte una respuesta concreta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: he editado las partes que bueno tenia problemas